# How do I create Excel worksheets at runtime that cache a data set in the data island

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

I have created an excel add-in that allows data to be downloaded into any excel workbook. The downloaded data is always placed in a new worksheet, but the workbook can also have worksheets that are not managed by the add-in.

Now I would like to store settings for each managed sheet (so I can refresh the sheet at a later date from the same data source etc.), preferably using the [cached] attribute to store to the VSTO datastore for each sheet. The problem is I don't seem to have access to a DataStore at the add-in level (I can create a Visual Studio project specifically for a workbook and create one there, but not in the project for the addin).

How can I dynamically create a datastore from the add-in / application level? Any hints / advice / links to tutorials are welcome, as I am finding it hard to find any information on this subject.

Comment: Franchesca did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem and the MSDN docs are not helping.

Comment: @JonathanSewell I ended up serializing the data for my Add-in into a "very hidden" excel worksheet. The data island cache seems to only work if you have a VSTO project of the "Workbook" type rather than the "Add-in" type, i.e. it is available at the document level, but not at the application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: I can't use the data island from the application level.